Why do my local folder names differ from the remote repo folder names?
How is this even possible?
Here are my local folders (example)
/features
   /AS
   /auth
   /chargers
   /chargingHistory

And my remote folders. (They are the same branch)
/features
   /AS
   /Auth
   /Chargers
   /ChargingHistory

I made changes to my the folder name in another branch, I just don't understand how it can be affecting my current branch. And I have not pulled from the branch where folder name changes were made to the current branch. Because of this, it is causing a build error..
It is affecting all the other branches except for the one where actual changes were made :(
The remote branches are fine, it is just that it is causing unnecessary build errors and I would not be able to see the actual errors in the future
How can I fix this?

My machine is macOS btw.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Does this answer your question? git different folder casing in branches and ls-remote

What difference are you talking about? Is this question about case (in)sensitivity or something else?

@dan1st yes case insensitivity as well as newly renamed  folders from another branch (A) appearing in another branch (B) with nothing inside them, when I did not pull from A to B

Git can be configured to be a case sensitive or not.
Looks like on your case that git is configured not to be case sensitive
TL;DR;
# Change the case flag to false so that git will trach the changes
git config core.ignorecase false

Long Demo, and how how to fix it:
#!/bin/bash

# Clear any exsiting code
rm -rf /tmp/remoteRepository
rm -rf /tmp/localRepository

### Create the dummy repository
git init --bare /tmp/remoteRepository

### Clone the repository
git clone /tmp/remoteRepository /tmp/localRepository

### Switch to the new working directory
cd /tmp/localRepository

###
### Setup the ignorecase flag for the repository
###
git config core.ignorecase true

## Create come content
mkdir -p AAA-folder
echo 'text' > AAA-folder/AAA-file.txt

### Commit the changes
git add AAA-folder/AAA-file.txt
git commit -m "Added AAA-file.txt"

### Push the changes to the remote repository
git push origin main

### Lets now change the folder name
mv AAA-folder aaa-folder

## Let check the staging area for changes
##
## >>> No changes !!!
git status

## List local files and directories
echo "----------------------------------------------------"
echo "Local files:"
echo ""
ls | grep *-folder

## List local files as they are "stored" in git
echo "----------------------------------------------------"
echo "Local git file names:"
echo ""
git ls-tree  main --name-only

## List remotes file and folders
echo "----------------------------------------------------"
echo "Remote files:"
echo ""
git ls-tree -r origin/main --name-only

# Change the case flag to false so that git will trach the changes
git config core.ignorecase false

# Verify that now we see the changes
echo "----------------------------------------------------"
git status



I would need to take some time of out my day to get that setup, since I have some urgent tickets to handle. Thanks! I really appreciate the in depth response. I ended up reverting to folder names to the original for a quick fix.

Glad to help, If it helped you feel free to accept it as answer :-)
